# Which is more efficient: every loop or afterwards?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, signal-processing, esp32, data-acquisition

Planning to collect some sensor data with an Arduino (or ESP32) and looking through other people's code I noticed **two variants, generally, to process sensor data**.

1. Collect, average and subtract some initial calibration value **within the loop**.
2. Collect all data, then process **after the loop**.

Some data qualities (in my example):

- data sampled at 100Hz
- 2-3 channels (imagine gyroscope sensor, natural signal frequency.... maybe 1-10Hz for anything useful?)
- some baseline calibration window before is subtracted, e.g. 100 datapoints / 1s

Pseudocode:

```
//variant 1) process within loop
loop() {
  read_data=readsensor();
  read_data=smooth(read_data);
  read_data=subtract(read_data,baseline);
  data_store[cnt]=read_data;
  cnt++;
}

//variant 2) after
loop() {
  read_data=readsensor();
  data_store[cnt]=read_data;
  cnt++;
}
process() { //called after loop 'finishes'
  data_store=smooth(data_store)
  data_store=subtract(data_store, baseline)
}
```

I understand that `1` will impact processing time during acquisition and `2` afterwards. I'm interested in coming up with the fastest way (i.e. time after recording) to the best version of the data (i.e. smoothed, subtracted, etc). Concrete questions:

Questions:

- Is there some sort of optimization implemented in Arduino, that would make `2` faster than `1` - or can this fundamentally be implemented faster than `1`? (this is my hunch)
- is there some fundamental engineering principles that would suggest `1` rather than `2` (based on sampling theorem etc)?
- Are there some general rules of thumb on the Arduino (-compatible) platform?

Any other advice is very welcome!

Comment: The variants basically have different sampling rates, is this important to you? Or when you say "data sampled at 100 Hz" do you have some (not seen in the pseudocode) synchronization which makes you take sample at specific intervals (so the samplerate is the same in both variants)?

Comment: the timing is essentially not important to me, I just want to classify the samples based on features later. As long as it's always sampled at same frequency, and around the range of 10-1000Hz (which should be achievable for Arduinos/ESP32s easily I guess), this should be fine, I guess. However, I would ideally want the result of that classification as fast as possible - that is - aside from the speed of the classifier itself

Comment: In some applications you can get improvements by using non-causal filtering. In some applications latency must be minimized. Really it depends on the details of your requirements.

Comment: Because you mention sampling theorem. If you don't use some kind of a timer to trigger the sample collection, then samplerate will depend on the speed of the code around the sampling part. Then if you do variant the "every loop" variant you may find out that different loop iterations take slightly different times (e.g. it may be that division routine's run time depends on data). Then your sampling is at irregular intervals, which may or may not be important for your application.

Comment: Oh right, I planned to use a start and stop button essentially. It's an excellent point, I assumed, microprocessors essentially run at 'the same speed' when it comes to processing under 1kHz. This may not be the case!

Comment: It's not about the start/stop button. It's when the successive invocations of `readsensor()` will happen. The usual way is to set up a timer that "calls" readsensor() each 10ms for example. This way you'll know the data samples are collected exactly 10.000ms apart and not affected by the potentially variable "every loop" processing time

Comment: I understand, this was merely to point out that a) I assumed the loop time is consistent for slow speeds b) that the only timing component beyond the loop-time is a start-stop signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, to answer your questions directly:

- Version 2 (all else being equal, and assuming the code takes equal time) will always be slower, as it has to do the computations in the end. There's no optimization that can be applied by the compiler here, and the Arduino environment is not changing this either - it is just a thin wrapper above the C compiler (gcc in most cases). It's worth measuring how much slower it is, your computations may be trivial and the slowdown be unnoticeable.
- as discussed in the comments, in some cases data **has** to be collected at a fixed sample rate (e.g. audio). For your application that might not be the case, it's your call here. Also keep in mind that "variable loop time" could be misleading, the variability may be too little to matter. So for data that needs fixed sample rate, the approaches, sorted from best to worst are

  - using a timer/interrupt to trigger successive samplings
  - your approach #2
  - your approach #1
- in general in engineering, data collected at a variable sample rate has a number of undesirable properties, for example even doing something as simple as averaging is conceptually harder. The data samples represent differing amounts of time, so their relative weights are unequal. If you insist on mathematical correctness, then you'd need to store timestamps beside the sample data and use those to compute relative weights and use that to compute the average. If you don't insist... then it's your call, really, but it's harder to reason about the results you're getting.
- any generic rules of the thumb is a really vague question. Keep in mind that if you've written code for a PC using gcc, then code for a MCU using gcc is not that much different, same programming concepts apply with regards to what the compiler sees and can optimize. There's no hidden ingredient to Arduino in general. You just need to be aware that memory is much more limited, the codespace is limited, debugging is harder, the MCU could be kind of slow, and especially slow in some cases (like floating point math, trig functions, etc.)

Comment: thanks a lot for this kind answer, I realize, for experts many of these thought processes are next to trivial - I appreciate the long and patient answer and it will take some time to fully digest and implement in the project. I usually program in Matlab, and there are a lot of optimizations that occur if you write programs in a way that is optimal to process / optimize

Comment: Understandable, have a great day :) It should be noted that compared to Matlab, in C and especially the type of C code seen in systems programming usage there's not much more than meets the eye. As Linus Torvalds once said "it's about writing almost-portable assembly language". Of course, Arduino uses C++ which can be complex and hide a lot of technical detail, but again in embedded programming that is typically not the case, it's used almost like C.

Answer (score 1):

The timing is important but there are much more considerations when designing a microcontroller firmware. Your question reminded me of my main concern when I started designing and commissioning microcontroller-based boards in 1995 and this concern was how to solve the EMC (electromagnetic compatibility) by firmware.

It happens that this is called **defensive programming**, **EMC-aware programming** or **Immunity-aware programming**.

One of the conclusions to reduce the noise effect was to collect the physical inputs at the beginning of each loop and apply the physical outputs at the end of each loop when it is possible. Inside the loop, the physical interaction with the external circuit must be reduced. But there is more to learn on this subject. A lot of techniques help you deploying your circuit in a real world.

I tried to find again the important Application notes provided by Motorola that helped me in my job at the time and I can find AN1263 but this was not the only important document on this interesting subject and there are new studies that confirm and add to these conclusions. Search for firmware defensive programming or immunity-aware programming and you will find a lot of interesting information.

Comment: thank you, very interesting, I will look into this!